# Does Jason Hickey's Ocaml book have answers publicly?

Tags: ocaml

I am reading the Ocaml book by Jason Hickey and doing the exercise at the end of each chapter, but I can't find the answers anywhere googling. I emailed the jyh at cs.caltech.edu a couple days ago but he hasn't replied yet. I just wanna ask around to see if anybody has them already. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure you'll find 'official' solutions, but many StackOverflow users are happy to answer OCaml questions. Just post the interesting questions and your solution/questions and we'll do our best to help!

Comment: Yeah, I figured... On his website, he said if anybody want the answers, email him; so I thought there might be someone who had emailed him before. But it seems like nobody has the actual answers. I'll just post my questions instead. Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that you aren't or you didn't convince him you are an instructor.

Comment: No, I didn't try since I am not. Maybe that's why I didn't get it? But anyway, I'll just post questions. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no publicly available set of answers. Sorry :-(